# lower self to higher self

Tags: vivekananda

To gain self realization we are going through lower self (earning money, career etc.) to higher self. Swami Vivekananda said “Unselfishness is the denial of the lower or apparent self” and it comes gradually by lots of practice. Swami ji said “Try to be pure and unselfish---that is the whole of religion”. In the period of lower self (as described selfish motive) when we are busy with our lower self for our career, earning money .are we commit sin as swami ji said “selfishness is the chief sin”. And in today’s world how much appropriate with this philosophy. You can try it but you can’t achieve truly or absolute unselfishness because of various circumstances then what will it call a selfish act or a unselfish act.